# Switch user after ssh into server using the crypto/ssh in golang

Tags: go, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm using the crypto/ssh package to successfully login to a remote server over ssh and run my commands. However, i seem to not be able to switch the user(lower privilege) and run commands.

```
cmd = 'whoami && sudo su spinner && whoami'
output, err := RemoteRun("ubuntu", IP, key, cmd)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Couldn't run the command on the remote server.")
}
fmt.Printf("SSH output: %s", output)
```

I get the following output:

```
SSH output: ubuntu
ubuntu
```

instead of

```
SSH output: ubuntu
spinner
```

Is this because of session is created with the ubuntu user ? Is there any way to have this running or am i missing something here ?

Comment: whoami runs after sudo exits in the shell that started sudo, not in the shell started *by* sudo su. This output is to be expected and has nothing to do with ssh. Try "sudo -u spinner whoami".

Answer (score 0):

Just did a slight change to the way i deliver the command and i get the expected output.

```
sudo su spinner -c "whoami"
```